# Estimating distribution of traffic across all Web pages

Tags: estimation, internet, zipf

The web is estimated to have approx 5 billion web pages ( http://www.worldwidewebsize.com/ ).  How would you go about estimating a CDF to know how many pages are required that make up, say, 90% of traffic?

I'm trying to apply Zipf's law but I'm not sure how to do it.  Of course, Zipf's law requires a parameter.  I'd like to estimate that.  As a starting point: What are typical values of that param in other domains? How consistent are they?

Then: Given that certain data is available (eg logs of requests of small sets of users) - how can we use those to estimate the right Zipf param?

Can we use PageRank data (which has lots published and can be calculated with enough computing power)? Can we use PageRank of a subset of the web?

How would you, as a statistician, go about trying to get some answers to this? Put the question concretely: What % of web pages get 90% of the traffic?

Comment: This paper might be helpful `Web Caching and Zipf-like Distributions: Evidence and Implications`